# Dynamically dropping files while reading using lapply

Tags: r, function, file, lapply

I've got the following code to read several files and append them separately to a single list *along with* the file name

```
foo <- function(fname){
fread(fname, skip = 5, header = TRUE, sep = " ") %>% 
mutate(fn = fname)
}

all <- lapply(files, FUN = foo)
```

**After the file is read,** I would like to insert a condition in the function which checks for some properties in the file failing which it drops the file along with the filename.

Not strictly related to reading a table but other files also

**Edit:**

I also use the following efficient method of doing it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177098/reading-seperate-text-files-and-saving-them-in-a-single-variable-as-seperate-dat/59177659#59177659):

```
all <- setNames(lapply(files, foo), files)
```

Comment: BTW - better to use `:=` for data.tables than `mutate`, and `[` for chaining, rather than `%>%`

Comment: Just a note note that `purrr::map_dfr` does the same thing as your current function out of the box if you assign names to your `files` vector.

Comment: @dww Since this is R, not C, I’d recommend writing this with a focus on *values* rather than statements, i.e. as `return(if (condition) x[, fn := fname] else NULL)`, and then drop the unnecessary `return` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following fairly simple option using Filter.
I used the condition in the Filter

```
all <- setNames(lapply(myFiles, function(x) {readLAS(x)}), myFiles)
all <- Filter(function(x) {area(x) >= 640}, all)
```

Not while running the lapply function but it uses only one extra line of code